# Makefile does not invoke action after touching the target file

Tags: makefile

Here is my Makefile:

```
NAME        := libftprintf.a

LIB         := ar rcs
CC          := gcc
CFLAGS      := -Wall -Wextra -Werror

SRCS_DIR    := ./sources/
HDRS_DIR    := ./headers/
OBJS_DIR    := ./objectives/

SRCS_FILES  := ft_conv.c \
                ft_eval_hex.c \
                ft_eval_number.c \
                ft_eval_string.c \
                ft_parsers.c \
                ft_strs_join.c \
                ft_eval_char.c \
                ft_eval_int.c \
                ft_eval_percent.c \
                ft_handler.c \
                ft_printf.c

HDRS_FILES  := ft_conv.h \
                ft_eval_hex.h \
                ft_eval_number.h \
                ft_eval_string.h \
                ft_parsers.h \
                ft_strs_join.h \
                ft_eval_char.h \
                ft_eval_int.h \
                ft_eval_percent.h \
                ft_handler.h \
                ft_printf.h

OBJS_FILES  := $(SRCS_FILES:.c=.o)

SRCS        := $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR),$(SRCS_FILES))
HDRS        := $(addprefix $(HDRS_DIR),$(HDRS_FILES))
OBJS        := $(addprefix $(OBJS_DIR),$(OBJS_FILES))

LIBFT_DIR   := ./libft/
LIBFT_NAME  := libft.a
LIBFT       := $(addprefix $(LIBFT_DIR),$(LIBFT_NAME))

RM          := rm -rf

all: $(NAME)

bonus: all
bonus_one: all
bonus_two: all

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(LIB) $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(LIBFT)

$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: $(SRCS_DIR)%.c $(HDRS) Makefile | $(OBJS_DIR) subsystem
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $(HDRS_DIR) -I $(LIBFT_DIR)

subsystem:
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR)

$(OBJS_DIR):
    mkdir $(OBJS_DIR)

clean:
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    $(RM) $(OBJS_DIR)

fclean: clean
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) fclean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all subsystem bonus bonus_one bonus_two clean fclean re
```

The problem is so: if I do `make all`, then `touch libftprintf.a` I would expect that `make all` will rebuild `libftprintf.a` since it was changed and target `all` depends on that file. However, make does nothing and I can't understand this behavior.
Also, there is one more minor issue: during `make all` I create a directory `objectives` where I store all `.o` files. Calling `make fclean` and `make all` entirely rebuilds the target, however calling `make re` results in an error:

```
rm -rf ./objectives/
rm -rf *libft objectives here*
rm -rf libft.a
rm -rf libftprintf.a
make: *** No rule to make target `objectives', needed by `objectives/ft_conv.o'.  Stop.
```

If I call `make re` right after this error, the target builds as always. Also, if I change `re` target to this, I do not receive any errors:

```
re:
    @$(MAKE) fclean
    @$(MAKE) all
```

Could not find solutions to my problems anywhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touching `libprintf.a` won't cause anything to rebuild.  Make rebuilds targets that are out of date.  Out of date means that either the target doesn't exist, or some prerequisite of the target is *newer* than the target.

After you run make then `libprintf.a` is up to date, which means it's newer than all its prerequisites.  Running `touch libprintf.a` just makes it even newer than its prerequisites than it was before, so make still considers it up to date.

If you want to rebuild `libprintf.a` you need to touch (or delete) one of its prerequisites, not the target itself.

The reason for your second issue seems to be related to the makefile in the `libft` subdirectory.  It seems like you're using the `--no-print-directories` option here: you should avoid using that, at least as long as you're debugging, so that you can see where make is going and which makefile it's running.